# sudo apt install works, but sudo apt-get purge --autoremove leaving a lot of junk on my system. Can't remove them

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I just installed neofetch using `sudo apt install neofetch.` When I went to uninstall it with  `sudo apt-get purge --autoremove`, I noticed there were many packages that it never removed along with a bunch of fonts. I had to go back and autoremove each package it left behind, freeing up 10MB of space, it still can't remove the font folders because (folder not empty). Am I using these commands wrong or is it meant to work this way?

```
dpkg: warning: while removing fonts-urw-base35, directory '/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35' not empty so not remove
dpkg: warning: while removing fonts-urw-base35, directory '/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35' not empty so not rem
Purging configuration files for poppler-data (0.4.11-1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-Korea1' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-Japan2' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-Japan1' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-GB1' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-CNS1' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/fonts/cmap' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing poppler-data, directory '/usr/share/fonts/cMap' not empty so not removed
Purging configuration files for gsfonts (1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.5) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing gsfonts, directory '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing fonts-noto-mono, directory '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto' not empty so not removed
Purging configuration files for fonts-droid-fallback (1:6.0.1r16-1.1build1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing fonts-droid-fallback, directory '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid' not empty so not removed
```

Comment: You show a command that will install `neofetch`, but your subsequent command that contained `purge` did **not** provide any package to remove thus only acted on prior package(s) & not `neofetch`.

Comment: The "not empty so not removed" messages are about font directories where fontconfig has dropped `.uuid` files. When the package uninstalls, APT can't remove these directories, not even when you `--purge`, because it finds these stray files. The messages (and remnant directories) are mostly harmless - albeit an ugly wart on Ubuntu's neat package management.